# Cannot run Google Map V2 on android device

Tags: android, google-maps

i have a problem running the map on my device it always says: [image]

i also follow this guide on [how to configure the google play service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_and_configure_the_google_play_services_sdk) to run in my application but still no luck. i'm running it on android device and building it on android studio

Comment: you have to Update Google-Play-Services in Android Device.

Comment: which android `os` and `device` u r using ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing has nothing to do with the link you have mentioned and the Google Play services SDK. It is just because you don't have the right version of Google Play services running on your device.

- If you are using a physical device clicking on the button that says "Update" should do it.(Just make sure you are connected to the internet)
- If you are working on an emulator, sadly, this won't work. What you have to do in this case is go to AVD Manager and create a new device with target set as "Google API(Whatever API level you are using)".

If you don't find the Google API in the list of targets, just download Google API from the SDK Manager for whatever API level you are working on.

Comment: thanks for the answer but my play service is already updated there is no update button on google play since it's already updated and i already downloaded the google play services even in froyo from my sdk manager but still that won't solve the problem

Comment: So you are working on a physical device then, are you?

Answer (score 1):

Just Click the Update button to update your google play services in your device.

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem because my google play service is already updated

Comment: do you follow the guides correctly? how about your api keys ?

Comment: yes i have my Client ID for installed applications from the google console.

Comment: @waelhe : its not about `api-key`. Its about the **google play service** which is already installed in that device. That is back dated.